# How to Search in in list inside infopath form in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: infopath

I want to search in a list inside infopath form and if the list item found then I want to populate the other data. Any answer how i can procede? Like there should be one textbox and a submit button, and when an user put something and click on search then if the record is present then the other fields should auto populate.  Any answer?

Comment: can you describe it with conditions and rules

Comment: U can add a repeating table and in the button click you can show the search results also.

Answer (score 2):

Create a secondary data source to the list. Set the field in the query fields node to the desired lookup value and query the data source. Populate the other fields from the returned result, if any.

If this sounds a bit vague, consider providing a better description of the issue.